# p_mask=p_mask[span_idx].tolist(),AttributeError: - 'list' object has no attribute 'tolist'

Tags: python, pipeline, attributeerror, huggingface-transformers

I'm getting the following error when I attempt to pass a question and context to a Transformer pipeline. The abort is actually occurring in the HuggingFace code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pipeline.py", line 66, in <module>
    main()
  File "pipeline.py", line 63, in main
    answer = query(value)
  File "pipeline.py", line 45, in query
    answer = qa(question=question, context=context)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/question_answering.py", line 248, in __call__
    return super().__call__(examples[0], **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/base.py", line 915, in __call__
    return self.run_single(inputs, preprocess_params, forward_params, postprocess_params)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/base.py", line 921, in run_single
    model_inputs = self.preprocess(inputs, **preprocess_params)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/question_answering.py", line 316, in preprocess
    p_mask=p_mask[span_idx].tolist(),
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tolist'
```

I am executing the code on a Raspberry Pi 4 arm71 CPU. I am using  Transformer version 4.11.2 and PyTorch version 1.7.0a0.  The code executes successfully under Windows 10.

Here is the code...

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
import os, sys
from transformers import pipeline
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification
#import torchaudio
import torch
#from speaking import speak

# globals
context = ""
model = None
qa = pipeline("question-answering")  # set up the model pipeline once

queries = { # set up dictioanry to hold questions
    "Question01": "How old are the Albuquerque volcanoes?",
    "Question02": "Where does andesitic compositions exist?",
    "Question03": "What is Tephrochronology?",
    "Question04": "Do volcanoes exist on other planets?",
    "Question05": "What type of volcano is Cerro Verde?",
    "Question06": "How old is the oldest rock in Albuqueruqe?",
    "Question07": "What does the gradual weathering of the loose cinders create?",
    "Question08": "What causes fissure eruption of the Albuquerque Volcanoes?",
    "Question09": "What is the name of the composite volcanoe that is 2.5 million years old?",
    "Question10": "What are the gas bubble in basalt called?",
    "Question11": "What do rocks in the Palomas Volcanic Field consist of?",
    "Question12": "What are the volcanic features of the Palomas Volcanic Field?",
    "Question13": "Where is the ZUNI-BANDERA FIELD AND MCCARTY'S LAVA FLOW located?",
    "Question14": "What surface is fairly common to many pahoehoe flows?",
    "Question15": "How far does the The Navajo Dine volcanic field extend?",
    "Question16": "How was the Valles Caldera formed?",
    "Question17": "What is the largest volcanic field within the Rio Grande rift?",
    "Question18": "What geologic feature is located in the central part of Charette Mesa, northwest of Wagon Mound?",
    "Question19": "Where did the most recent volcictivity occur in New Mexico?",
    "Question20": "what are the floors of the Jornada caves covered with?",
    "Question21": "The Albuquerque Volcanoes we see today are are the result of what?",
    "Question22": "In what year did the eruption of Mount Pinatubo occur?",
    "Question23": "How does volcanic ash form?",
    "Question24": "What are volocanic mudflows called?",
    "Question25": "What volcano is located about 33 miles east of Raton?"
    }

def query(question):
    # Generating an answer to the question in context
    # qa = pipeline("question-answering")
    answer = qa(question=question, context=context)

    # save the model
    #torch.save(qa.model.state_dict(), "C:\\tmp")

    # Print the answer
    print("{0}: ".format(question))
    print(f"Answer: '{answer['answer']}' with score {answer['score']}")

def main():
    global qa, context

    # get the volcano corpus
    with open('volcanic.corpus', encoding="utf8") as file:
        context = file.read().replace('\n', '')

    # process each query
    for value in queries.values():
        answer = query(value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Are you running the same versions of transformers and PyTorch on your Windows 10 machine?

Comment: Pi:
transformers==4.11.2
torch==1.7.0a0
torchvision==0.8.0a0+45f960c

Win:
torch==1.7.1 
torchaudio==0.7.2 
torchvision==0.8.2
transformers==4.6.1

Comment: Does your code work when you install the same version of transformers on your Raspberry?

Comment: That fixed it.  I matched versions and the error is gone.